# ¿Como convertir un objeto en una cadena de parámetros codificada para URL?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto que quiero convertirlo en una cadena de parámetros codificada para `URL`.

Quiero convertir este objeto:

```
let params = {
  dateFrom: '2018-01-01',
  dateTo: '2018-01-18',
  types: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

A esto:

```
params = 'dateFrom=2018-01-01&dateTo=2018-01-18&types%5B%5D=1&types%5B%5D=2&types%5B%5D=3';
```

Answer (score 2):

### Opción 1

Si `jQuery` esta dispobible, entonces podría usar [jQuery.param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

> Crea una representación serializada de una matriz, un objeto simple o un objeto jQuery adecuado para su uso en una cadena de consulta `URL` o solicitud `Ajax`.

#### Demo

```js
let params = {
  dateFrom: '2018-01-01',
  dateTo: '2018-01-18',
  types: [1, 2, 3],
  is_date: new Date(),
  is_bool: new Boolean(),
  is_null: null
}
console.log($.param(params))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Opción 2

En `Javascript` puro

```js
function objectToParams(object) {
  let params = [];
  setParams(params, object);
  return params.join('&');

  function setParams(params, value, name = '') {

    if (name && isAValue(value)) {
      params.push([name, value + ''].map(encodeURIComponent).join('='));
    } else if (name && Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.map((val, index) => {
        setParams(params, val, name + '[' + (isAValue(val) ? '' : index) + ']');
      });
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      Object.keys(value).map(prop => {
        setParams(params, value[prop], name ? name + '[' + prop + ']' : prop);
      })
    }
  }

  function isAValue(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' ||
      typeof value === 'string' ||
      value instanceof Date ||
      value instanceof Boolean ||
      value === null;
  }
}

//

let params = {
  is_number: new Number(1),
  is_number2: 2,
  is_string: '2018-01-18',
  is_string2: new String('2018-01-18'),
  is_array: [1, 2, 3],
  is_object: {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'},
  is_date: new Date(),
  is_bool: new Boolean(),
  is_null: null
}
console.log(objectToParams(params))
```

Answer (score 1):

## En Javascript moderno

```js
function objectToParams(object){
    var pares = Object.entries(object);
    var paresConRepe = [].concat.apply([],pares.map(
        ([key, val])=>(val instanceof Array ? val.map(v=>[`${key}[]`,v]) :
            val && val.toJSON ? [[key, val.toJSON()]] :
            val instanceof Object ? Object.entries(val).map(([k,v])=>[`${key}[${k}]`,v]) :
            [[key, val]]
        )
    ));
    var up = new URLSearchParams(paresConRepe);
    return up.toString();
}

let params = {
  dateFrom: '2018-01-01',
  dateTo: '2018-01-18',
  types: [1, 2, 3],
  person: {name:'Bob', lastName:'Esponja'},
  is_bool: true,
  is_null: null,
  dateX: new Date('2018-01-18')
}

console.log(objectToParams(params))
```

Nótese

1. `Object.entries` para transformar un objeto `{[key: string]: value}` en un array `[key, value][]`.
2. `pares.map` que para cada par devuelve un arreglo de pares (para manejar valores que son objetos y arreglos). `pares.map(f)` donde `f: [key,value][] => [key,value][][]`.
3. `[].concat.apply([], T[][])` para obtener un `T[]`
4. Uso `([a, b])` como parámetro de la función para poder usar `a`, `b` en vez de poner `(par)` y después tener que poner `par[0]` y `par[1]`.
5. La guarda `val.toJSON` trata de capturar cualquier valor u objeto que sepa "JSONearse", suponiendo que si uno lo usa es que va a saber recibirlo (con las limitaciones que el formato JSON tiene. Ahí se podrían agregar otras opciones en caso de ser necesario. Nótese también que `dateX` no es una fecha sino un Date de Javascript que viene a ser un `timestamp` o `datetime` según quién lo nombre.

Comment: Me gusta tu propuesta, pero le veo un detalle, `dateX` no aparece en el resultado

Comment: Ah, es verdad, quise probar, y me quedé a mitad de camino. Lo arreglo para que quede registro (cuanto más arreglado, menos elegante)